# Get tax RATE for an order or invoice

Tags: tax, shipping-address, magento-1.4

I am learning how to navigate through Magento; there is definitely a learning curve and I've not be exposed to this much abstraction before.  Overall, it's been tough but a good experience.

My question is how to get the tax RATE on an invoice or order.  I do not want to get the tax amount, but rather the rate.

I'm thinking this is associated with the shipping address.  My company's orders have only one shipping address and all items are associated to the one shipping address.  How would I get this?

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! Tax nexus can be terribly complicated. This is because the rules and laws vary from state to state and even county to county. You should consult your tax code and the company's lawyers and accountants re: tax nexus and calculation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tax rate is not based on order, but on order item, so you will need to check these: `$orderItem->getTaxPercent()`.

For invoice items you need to request the associated order item by calling `$invoiceItem->getOrderItem()->getTaxPercent()`.

To get the whole tax information of an order, you may use `$order->getFullTaxInfo();`, which returns the whole tax calculation result.

Comment: Thanks.  This shows some cleverness on Magento's part as well to have a method like `$invoiceItem->getOrderItem()` to map back to the corresponding item.  Good post.